# How to redirect to desire page using devise gem , and making the root_path to sign_in page?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I Have added the scope to my devise code that is

```
devise_scope :authorizes do
 authenticated :authorizes do
   root :to => "auth#main"
end
  unauthenticated :authorizes do
   root :to => "devise/session#new"
  end
end
root :to => "auth#main"
```

1. What is the problem in the `scope`?
2. error at `localhost:3000` is `NO route matches [get] "/"`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your **application_controller**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if authorize_signed_in?
    amain_path
  end
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  if authorize_signed_in?
    new_authorize_session_path
  end
end
```